# How would I go about calculating the index field / tag field?

Tags: computer-architecture

For index field I got '9' because 2^(9) = 512 words. But I'm stuck on what the formula for calculating the tag field is... any ideas?

Given a cache that holds 512 words and block size of one word. Assume 32-bit addresses. The index field is ____ bit. The tag field is ____ bit.

Answer (score 0):

Okay let's go step by step.

The cache has $512$ words, each block is $1$ word. Hence the cache has $512$ blocks. Since you have not mentioned anything about ways(not an n-way associative cache) and are actually demanding index bits(not a fully associative cache) I am assuming it is a direct-mapped cache.
So now since we had $512$ blocks(/lines) we need $9$ bits($log_2{2^9}$) to uniquely identify a block, so we have $9$ index bits. Now assuming the memory is byte organised and the size of a word is $4$ bytes, we need $2$ bits to uniquely identify a byte from the $1$ word block. Now we have $32 - 9 - 2=21$ bits remaining and they are the tag bits.

Hope it helps!